# Qt split mainwindow into four widgets

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, qt-creator

Please can you help me. 
I have a classic mainwindow in Qt project and i want to split it into four **SAME** parts - widgets. I need to have a one widget in the first part and another parts have to be empty. And after that, later in my program, i wan to add another widgets to another parts. Important is to split the mainwindow to four parts for widgets of the **same size**.

I have this code but it splits a mainwindow into four parts of different size. One is to big and another is just very small etc.

In scene[..]->gameview are widgets to insert.

**NOTE:** I don't use a .ui file, I code everything manually.

```
        containter = new QWidget(this);
        container_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        containter2 = new QWidget(this);
        container_layout2 = new QVBoxLayout;
        central = new QWidget(this);


        splitter1->addWidget(scenes[0]->gameview);
        splitter1->addWidget(scenes[1]->gameview);



        container_layout->addWidget(splitter1);
        containter->setLayout(container_layout);

        splitter2->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
        splitter2->addWidget(containter);
        if(number_of_scenes == 3)
        {

            splitter3->addWidget(scenes[2]->gameview);
            splitter3->addWidget(new QWidget);
            container_layout2->addWidget(splitter3);
            containter2->setLayout(container_layout);
        }
        else if(number_of_scenes == 4)
        {

            splitter3->addWidget(scenes[2]->gameview);
            splitter3->addWidget(scenes[3]->gameview);
            container_layout2->addWidget(splitter3);
            containter2->setLayout(container_layout);
        }
        else
        {

             splitter3->addWidget(new QWidget);
             splitter3->addWidget(new QWidget);
             container_layout2->addWidget(splitter3);
             containter2->setLayout(container_layout);
        }

        splitter2->addWidget(containter2);
        layoutt->addWidget(splitter2);

        central->setLayout(layoutt);
        setCentralWidget(central);
```

Comment: Have a look at [QGridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html). The keyword is `stretchFactor`. This factor allows you to define how much proportional space one element in a layout should take.

Answer (score 1):

Try mdi area.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html There is also an example https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/mainwindows-mdi.htm some classmates used it for a game in one of my programming classes to do something along the lines of what you are describing.